# TypoScript with innerWrap and section_frame doesn't work anymore

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-8.x

We are reworking old TYPO3 projects and my problem is that the following condition doesn't work anymore, and nothing gets wrapped:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  key.field = section_frame
  100 = TEXT
  100.value = <div id="c{field:uid}" class="hotel">|</div>
}
```

So, `section_frame` is deprecated and got replaced by `frame_class` which would result in:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  key.field = frame_class
  100 = TEXT
  100.value = <div id="c{field:uid}" class="hotel">|</div>
}
```

But that doesn't work either. What else has to be changed to work with TYPO3 9.5 and `fluid_styled_content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the classes are not assigned by a numeric value but directly as a class string, you don't need any condition for that, but you can use the string data instead.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject >
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = TEXT
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  insertData = 1
  value = <div id="c{field:uid}" class="{field:frame_class}">|</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TypoScript is related to `Css_styled_content`. It cannot be integrated into `Fluid_styled_content`.

In your site package you have to override the default layout file of `Fluid_styled_content` and add an inline fluid condition at the appropriate place. Something like:

`{f:if( condition: data.frameClass, then: ' {data.frameClass}' )}